# How to display row data in column dynamically in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table data in the following format in Oracle:

```
Roll_No Paper Code    Inst_Code
1       71            10
1       72            10
1       73            10
2       71            10
2       73            10
2       75            10
3       72            11
3       73            11
4       71            11
4       73            11
```

and so on. 
I want to display the data in the following format dynamically...

```
Inst_Code    71     72      73     75
--------     ---    ---     ---    ---
10           2      1       2      1
11           1      1       2      0
```

Comment: So if somebody inserts paper code 78, you suddenly expect column 78 to show up?

Comment: i suspect it is `select paper_code, inst_code, count(*) from t group by paper_code, inst_code` and pivot by `paper_code` values ? Pivot columns `71`, `72` ... cannot be defined dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

```
with t(Roll_No,
Paper_Code,
Inst_Code) as
 (          select 1, 71, 10 from dual
  union all select 1, 72, 10 from dual
  union all select 1, 73, 10 from dual
  union all select 2, 71, 10 from dual
  union all select 2, 73, 10 from dual
  union all select 2, 75, 10 from dual
  union all select 3, 72, 11 from dual
  union all select 3, 73, 11 from dual
  union all select 4, 71, 11 from dual
  union all select 4, 73, 11 from dual)

select *
  from (select paper_code, inst_code, count(*) total
          from t
         group by paper_code, inst_code) pivot(sum(total) for paper_code in(71,
                                                                            72,
                                                                            73,
                                                                            75));
```

Comment: Please, explain why you used union all select. Also, 'with' what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can build an SQL doing that, given that you have a variable number or columns. The best I could find is some dynamic SQL that builds your query:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    vSQL              VARCHAR2(1000) :=
     'SELECT *
      FROM   (SELECT paper_code, inst_node
              FROM   test)
      PIVOT  (count(1)  FOR (paper_code) IN (PaperCodeList))
      order by inst_node';
    vPaperCodeList    VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG(paper_code || ' as "' || paper_code ||'"', ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY paper_code)  as list
      INTO vPaperCodeList
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT paper_code FROM test);

    vSQL      := REPLACE(
                         vSQL,
                         'PaperCodeList',
                         vPaperCodeList
                        );
    dbms_output.put_line(vSQL);
END;
/
```

This will build a query like the following:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2        FROM   (SELECT paper_code, inst_node
  3                FROM   test)
  4        PIVOT  (count(1)  FOR (paper_code) IN (71 as "71", 72 as "72", 73 as "73", 75 as "75"))
  5        order by inst_node;

 INST_NODE         71         72         73         75
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10          2          1          2          1
        11          1          1          2          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Franks answer won't work with dynamic list of columns as for pivot you have to declare all of them, thus their number can't vary. Another option than dynamically building SQL is to use XML (it can use "in ANY"):

```
SELECT *
     FROM (
            SELECT Roll_No,
                 Paper_Code,
                 Inst_Code
            FROM t
            )
            PIVOT XML(COUNT(Roll_No) AS "Value" FOR paper_code IN (ANY))
```

This way the output would be 2 columns: inst_code and paper_code_xml where you have all the paper_counts with their values:

```
 INST_CODE PAPER_CODE_XML
 10 <XMLTYPE>
 11 <XMLTYPE>
```

where the xml value is:

```
<PivotSet>
<item>
    <column name = "PAPER_CODE">71</column>
    <column name = "Value">2</column>
</item>
<item>
    <column name = "PAPER_CODE">72</column>
    <column name = "Value">1</column>
</item>
<item>
    <column name = "PAPER_CODE">73</column>
    <column name = "Value">2</column>
</item>
<item>
    <column name = "PAPER_CODE">75</column>
    <column name = "Value">1</column>
</item>
```